# How to use where clause with given numbers and show the person which rows contains given number

Tags: mysql

Given that I have four numbers: 2,4,6,8 to search in each row. If the row contains or matches the given numbers orderly or in any order it will show the person's name. I've tried some ways but unlucky.

Here is the screenshot of my data table:
https://pasteboard.co/HYs6pAi.png

```
Select Person from tblluckynumber where num1=2 and num2=4 and num3=6 and num4=8
```

The output should show the Person's name in Query: Ken and Josh because they matches the four given numbers

Comment: Your link looks broken. Would you please update your question to add sample data and expected output **as text** ?

Comment: My link is not broken sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Person
FROM tblluckynumber
WHERE num1 IN (2, 4, 6, 8) AND 
num2 IN (2, 4, 6, 8) AND
num3 IN (2, 4, 6, 8) AND 
num4 IN (2, 4, 6, 8)
```

Comment: I will try that sir. Thanks.